# How to share Sonarqube Dashboard?

Tags: sonarqube

I have created a SonarQube dashboard, which gives overview of my team's SonarQube projects. However, I'm unable to share the dashboard with my team. How can I share the dashboard? What permission does the administrator need to enable so that I can share it? We're using SonarQube Version 5.6.7.

Comment: Did you see [this](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE52/Customizing+Dashboards) page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the [Share Dashboards and Filters](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE56/Authorization#Authorization-GlobalPermissions) permission. Then you'll be able to make your dashboards public and @Jeroen Heier pointed out in his comment, your team mates will be able to [subscribe](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE56/Customizing+Dashboards#CustomizingDashboards-ManagingDashboards) to them.

Note that dashboards were dropped in SonarQube 6.2.

Comment: And we just updated our SonarQube server and now we don't have dashboards :-P Solved that problem, you can't share what you don't have :-)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative (at least in SonarQube 5.6.3) if you don't have the mentioned permission, is to create a "comparison" for the projects you are interested in. Accessible via the main menu/More/Compare Projects. You can then add projects and metrics, and once you are satisfied, save/share the URL. This can serve as a dashboard of sorts.